# writing into a csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

heres my little program. at the end i want to write the names and passwords
into csv file like this:

```
Jack,9978
Sara,1647
```

but i cant!? my program output is correct but when i write it into csv it goes like:

```
Jack9978,Sara1674
```

how will you fix it?

```
import hashlib
import csv

answer = []
usr_pas = []

with open('...', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for word in reader:
        usr_pas.append(word)

for i in range(999, 10000):
    num = str(i)
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(num.encode('utf-8'))
    hsh = m.hexdigest()
    hash_dict = {hsh: num}
    for key in list(hash_dict.items()):
        for value in usr_pas:
            if key[0] == value[1]:
                answer.append(value[0] +','+ key[1])

file = open("...", 'w', newline='')
with file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(i.strip().replace(',', '') for i in answer)
file.close()
```

what did i wrong!?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (lines with comments are changed):

```
import hashlib
import csv

answer = []
usr_pas = []

with open('...', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for word in reader:
        usr_pas.append(word)

for i in range(999, 10000):
    num = str(i)
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(num.encode('utf-8'))
    hsh = m.hexdigest()
    hash_dict = {hsh: num}
    for key in list(hash_dict.items()):
        for value in usr_pas:
            if key[0] == value[1]:
                answer.append(value[0] +','+ key[1] + '\n') #added '\n' at the end

file = open("...", 'w', newline='')
with file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(i for i in answer) #removed i.replace
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a csv file with multiple lines instead of one. If so, my suggestion is to use `csv.csvwriter.writerows` instead of `csv.csvwriter.writerow`. The latter is designed to write a single row. See the official document [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow). Indeed multiple lines might be created with `\n` manipulator, it means a single line with multiple elements that contains "new line", which seems awkward.

Since we can use the default delimiter (comma), we just need to manage each element in the line as a tuple (or a list). Answers should be added into list `answer` like this:

`answer.append((value[0], key[1]))`

while we write rows in this way:

`writer.writerows(answer)`

Let's put them together:

```
import hashlib
import csv 

answer = []
usr_pas = []

with open('...', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for word in reader:
        usr_pas.append(word)

for i in range(999, 10000):
    num = str(i)
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(num.encode('utf-8'))
    hsh = m.hexdigest()
    hash_dict = {hsh: num}
    for key in list(hash_dict.items()):
        for value in usr_pas:
            if key[0] == value[1]:
                # answer.append(value[0] +','+ key[1])
                answer.append((value[0], key[1]))

file = open("...", 'w', newline='')
with file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    # writer.writerow(i.strip().replace(',', '') for i in answer)
    writer.writerows(answer)
file.close()
```